# Simple AngularJS App won´t work. How to debug this?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I´m tryinng to improve our giant js (jquery) legacy with angularjs.
Now my first problem, starting with the simplified code:

angularApp.js:

```
angular.module('ngSomeApp', [])

    // changed interpolate provider to avoid smarty cancer
    .config(['$interpolateProvider', function ($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
    }])

    // getting party started
    .controller('ngSomeController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.test = 'Hello World';
        console.log($scope.test);
    }]); // module closed
```

DOM:

```
<html>
    <head>
        // loading angular.min.js (1.4.6)
        // loading angularApp.js
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="ngSomeApp">
            [[2+2]]
            <div ng-controller="ngSomeController">
                [[2+2]]
                [[test]]
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

My problem is, that:

- [[2+2]] and [[test]] are not rendered
- there is no error in console (and no "Hello World")
- {literal}{{2+2}}{/literal} (we use smarty) and non-modified interpolate povider also don´t work
- If i console.log(angular.module('ngSomeApp')); at the end of the angularApp.js:

  > Object {_configBlocks: Array[0], _runBlocks: Array[0], requires: Array[0], name: "ngSomeApp", requiresOriginal: undefined}

The code is so simple and i don´t see the issue. Do you have any idea? Do you see any problem in my code?

Comment: Can you provide the jsfiddle with the problem

Answer (score 2):

**Your code works with 1.2.23, even with 1.4.2**

Note: I have not changed anything, apart from creating snippet.

```js
angular.module('ngSomeApp', [])

// changed interpolate provider to avoid smarty cancer
.config(['$interpolateProvider',
  function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
  }
])

// getting party started
.controller('ngSomeController', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.test = 'Hello World';
    console.log($scope.test);
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ngSomeApp">
  [[2+2]]
  <div ng-controller="ngSomeController">
    [[2+2]] [[test]]
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Then shouldn't the question be closed as the `problem cannot be reproduced`

Comment: You´re right, i also cannot reproduce this problem in external environment. Do you have tipps how i can debug this problem?